# AJAX & Java, JSP

Tags: jsp, ajax, java

Есть ли подводные камни в испольовании AJAX, Java, JSP вместе?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Определенно, там есть такие же проблемы, как при использовании `Java` и `JSP` без `Ajax`. А подводных камней может и не быть *вообще*, если грамотно писать код. Т.е. при понимании принципов работы, ошибок возникает намного меньше. А из дополнительных проблем и морок - дак это то, что в дополнение к `Java`, надо еще и `JavaScript` использовать, который, стало быть изучить тоже надо. *НО очень* советую использовать какие-нибудь `JavaScript` библиотеки, которые уберут очень много подводных камней и облегчат выполнение задачи. На сколько я знаю, `jQuery` довольно легкая и перспективная библиотека.
И еше: т.к. `AJAX` уже начинают использовать практически везде, даже где надо и не надо то, стало быть, можно быть уверенным, что разработчики постарались, чтобы приложения `Java-JSP-AJAX-...` - можно было сделать надежными и стабильными.
Надеюсь, на довольно поверхностный вопрос ответил достаточно отчетливо.